# Dynamically add element beside inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

Let's say I have 10 different input fields, each of them has an ID.

```html
<input id="blue">
<input id="pink">
<input id="red">
<!-- ... -->
```

Next to these input fields, I want to create an `<a>` element whose `href` attribute should dynamically include the ID of the button right next to it:

```html
<input id="blue">
<a href="mylink.com/blue"><a/>

<input id="pink">
<a href="mylink.com/pink"><a/>

<input id="red">
<a href="mylink.com/red"><a/>
```

This is the simple code I am working with:

```html
$('input').prepend('<a href="mylink.com/'+ID of the element next to this a tag+'/'</a>');
```

Comment: ...and what are your efforts towards it?

Comment: Do you have a question about this? Have you made any effort to solve this yourself? If so, please edit the question to include details of your code, and what your issues are

Comment: I just don´t know how to include these IDs for each element. I know how to create the <a> tag, but not sure how to assign each IDs to each specific <a> tag

Comment: For future reference, you should have included your javascript to create the <a> tag with some additional text covering the id insertion.
The stackoverflow community like to see you've at least tried.

Comment: Give each of the input common class, then it's very easy with `after` method.

Comment: OK sorry, here it is:
$('input').prepend('<a href="mylink.com/'+ID of the element next to this a tag+'/'</a>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.fn.preprend` method you are trying to use is not the right tool for this problem, since it inserts content *into* element, while you want to ippend it next to it as sibling.

When you need to operate on set of elements in similar way, you should consider giving them the same class name for easy DOM querying. Then it would be very easy with the help of [$.fn.after](https://api.jquery.com/after/) method:

```js
// $('input') will also work of course
$('.input').after(function () {
  return $('<a>', {
    href: 'http://mylink.com/' + this.id,
    text: this.id
  })
  // or return string:
  // return '<a href="http://mylink.com/' + this.id + '">' + this.id + '</a>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="blue" class="input">
<input id="pink" class="input">
<input id="red" class="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure js approach

https://jsfiddle.net/r5thro2w/

```
<input id="blue">
<input id="pink">
<input id="red">

window.onload = addAnchors();

function addAnchors() {
   let allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");   
   for(i=0;i<allInputs.length;i++) {    
    let anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.setAttribute('href',allInputs[i].getAttribute("id"));
    anchorTag.innerHTML = allInputs[i].getAttribute("id");
    allInputs[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterend", anchorTag);
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/18686/

```
<div class="myHref">
 <input class="clickMe" id="blue">
 <a class="link" href="hello.com"></a>
   </div>
     <div class="myHref">
<input class="clickMe" id="pink">
<a class="link" href="hello.com"></a>
</div>
    <div class="myHref">
  <input class="clickMe" id="red">
      <a class="link" href="hello.com"></a>
 </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.clickMe').change(function(e){
       var textInput    =   $(this).val();
   $ele = $(this).closest('.myHref').find('.link');
     var _href =$(this).closest('.myHref').find('.link').attr("href");

     $(this).closest('.myHref').find('.link').attr("href", _href +'#'+textInput);

 var _href2 =$(this).closest('.myHref').find('.link').attr("href");
alert(_href2);
 });
 });
```